# AD group owner cannot add new users

Tags: active-directory

I am the owner of an Active Directory group, but I do not have permissions to add users to the group. I am told that I need our AD admins to add the users, but it had made me wonder what rights a group owner has (and indeed, why bother making someone an owner) when they cannot add people to a group.

How is this permission denied to the owner and is there a way to check for it via some property of the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the "**Managed By**" tab of the group properties, there is a checkbox "**Manager can update membership list**", is that checked ?

Comment: You're right, it wasn't checked. What is the purpose of separating these rights? Why would someone manage a group they can not add users to - are there other implicit rights granted to a group owner, or is it more just so users can see who the primary point of contact would be?